# SQL Combine 2 Select Statements to get data from both rows

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, sql-server-2017

I have a table that contains 2 rows per record. the initial record and then the record when its ended they contain the same information apart from one column on the second row has the completed location.

```
eg 1st row 
Id, New ID, RecordType, Customer Name, Customer Address, Created,   Closed,   location 
1 , Null,   Initial,     John Smith,    1, long lane,   01/05/2019, 10/05/2019, Office
2nd row
Id, New ID, RecordType,  Customer Name, Customer Address, Created, Closed,    Location
2 , 1,     Completed,     John Smith,    1, long lane,   01/05/2019, 10/05/2019, Field
```

I want to report on the 1st row but I want the location from the second row, the second row links with the 1st row via the ID, and New ID field.

I've tried to use a CTE Query but the results returned are less than the results returned when just querying the 1st row.

```
WITH group1 AS (select * from a where closed is not null),
group2 AS (select location from a where closed is not null)
SELECT *
  FROM group1
  JOIN group2 ON group1.ID = group2.NewID ;
```

I hope this makes sense, just want some advice on how to join these 2 rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you need left join

```
WITH group1 AS (select * from a where closed is not null),
group2 AS (select location from a where closed is not null)
SELECT group1.*,group2.location
  FROM group1
  left JOIN group2 ON group1.ID = group2.NewID
```

even you dont need cte you can use selft join

```
select t1.*,t2.location
from a t1 left join a t2 on t1.ID = t2.NewID
where t1.closed is not null
```

Comment: Does this even need the CTEs? You could easily move the logic to the `WHERE` and `ON`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this might help .

```
select s1.*, s2.location as newlocation
 FROM tablename as s1
inner join 
 tablename as s2
 on
s1.Id=s2.new_id
```

you can join table with itself

Answer (score 0):

You need a left self join of the table:

```
select  
  a1.id, a2.newid, a2.recordtype,
  a1.customername, a1.customeraddress,
  a1.created, a1.closed, a2.location
from a a1 left join a a2
on a2.newid = a1.id 
where a1.newid is null
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct logic without CTEs is:

```
select t1.*, t2.location
from a t1 left join
     a t2
     on t2.NewID = t1.ID and
        t2.closed is not null
where t1.closed is not null
```